# Apply a calculation on columns (awk)

Tags: awk

I tried to make this calculation from the column 41 to the end of the line:

```
    awk '{ { split($10,a,":") } { split( a[4], b ,",") } {print b[1]+b[2]}}' filename
```

I know how to do this on just one column, but when I tried to do a loop it fails :

```
     awk '{for (i=10;i<=NF;i++) {split($i,a,":")} {split(a[4],b,",")} {print ( b[1]+b[2])}}' filename
```

The aim is to split each columns and to do the sum of those numbers :

> ./.:0:.,.,.:**0,0**:0,0

Here is what my file looks like :

```
Contig  POS  ID  REF  ALT  QUAL  FILTER  INFO  FORMAT  S155  S158  S168  S173  S175  S178  S180  S188  S189  S191  S193  S194  S196  S201  S205  S206  S208  S209  S210
NODE_14985_length_2800_cov_1.38384 67 999978 A C . PASS Ty=SNP;Rk=1;UL=19;UR=31;CL=.;CR=.;Genome=A;Sd=1 GT:DP:PL:AD:HQ ./.:8:.,.,.:8,0:71,0     ./.:0:.,.,.:0,0:0,0     ./.:0:.,.,.:0,0:0,0     ./.:0:.,.,.:0,0:0,0    ./.:0:.,.,.:0,0:0,0     ./.:0:.,.,.:0,0:0,0     ./.:0:.,.,.:0,0:0,0     ./.:0:.,.,.:0,0:0,0     ./.:0:.,.,.:0,0:0,0     ./.:0:.,.,.:0,0:0,0     ./.:0:.,.,.:0,0:0,0     ./.:0:.,.,.:0,0:0,0     ./.:0:.,.,.:0,0:0,0    ./.:0:.,.,.:0,0:0,0     ./.:0:.,.,.:0,0:0,0     ./.:0:.,.,.:0,0:0,0     ./.:0:.,.,.:0,0:0,0     ./.:0:.,.,.:0,0:0,0     ./.:0:.,.,.:0,0:0,0
```

Here is my actual output:

```
awk '{for (i=10;i<=NF;i++) {split($i,a,":")} {split(a[4],b,",")} {print b[1]+b[2]}}' file.vcf | head

0
0
0
0
0
```

I want a matrix of the calcul for each columns :

```
0 0 0 0 
1 2 0 6
2 0 0 8 
...
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Is the printf advised in your second - loop - code a typo?

Comment: can you show the expected output?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake, I used print before to use printf

Comment: This is my output :

`awk '{for (i=41;i<=NF;i++) {split($i,a,":")} {split(a[4],b,",")} {print b[1]+b[2]}}' file.vcf | head

0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0`

Comment: Correct mistakes (if any) in your answer and also include in your answer the expected output. Optionally provided the wrong output you are getting with your code.

Answer (score 0):

- changed the printf adding a print at the end (your printf need, at least, a space to separate results of the line)
- based on your sample change the 41 to a number lower than 28 (there is only 28 field for awk in this dataset)
- your different split are AFTER the loop, they  must be IN the loop scope (see where are the brace)

Modified code:

```
awk 'NR > 1 {
   for( i=41; i<=NF; i++) {
      split( $i, a, ":" )
       #print NF ":" i "[" $i "]  a[4]:" a[4]
      split( a[4], b, ",")
       #print i ": " b[1] " + " b[2] " : " b[1] + b[2]
      printf( "%d ",  b[1] + b[2])
      }
   print ""
   }' YourFile
```

Comment: `awk 'NR > 1 {for( i=41; i<=NF; i++) {split( $i, a, ":" ) split( a[4], b, ",")} {printf( "%d ",  b[1] + b[2])} print }' test `

0 
NODE_14985_length_2800_cov_1.38384 67 999978 A C . PASS Ty=SNP;Rk=1;UL=19;UR=31;CL=.;CR=.;Genome=A;Sd=1 GT:DP:PL:AD:HQ ./.:8:.,.,.:8,0:71,0   ./.:0:.,.,.:0,0:0,0     ./.:0:.,.,.:0,0:0,0

Comment: This is the output of your code ! It prints me the entire line of my file :S

Comment: sorry forget the last `""` on the print (so it print the full line by default)

Comment: `awk 'NR > 1 {for( i=11; i<=NF; i++) {split( $i, a, ":" ) split( a[4], b, ",")} {printf( "%d ", b[1] + b[2])} print ""}' test
0
0
`
It doesn't do the calculation on each columns, it prints me only for the first field of each line (my file test contain only 2 lines)

Comment: Strange, on my sample (take yours but modified some digit to have something different of 0 to add), calculation is ok and for each lines (except 1st). Could you modify your question to have a more accurate data sample to test (2 or 3 lines seems enough) ?

Comment: I made a few modifications on the code 
`awk 'NR > 1 {for( i=10; i<=NF; i++) {split( $i, a, ":" ) split( a[4], b, ","); printf( b[1]+b[2]"\t")} print "" }' `
Now it works, thanks a lot !